# ReactJs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ItemsServices' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here I am getting some problems with [AliceCarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676875/reactjs-filter-images-to-map-into-carousel) to map my response to display its images in the gallery.
I wanted to display the respective types of images for each gallery.

I am generally following [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676875/reactjs-filter-images-to-map-into-carousel) .

Any help or suggestion here to make it possible?
Thanks is advance.

//Js

```
class KitchenService extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0,
      responsive: { 1024: { items: 3 } },
      galleryItems: this.galleryItems(),
      services : this.props.resume,
      ...props,
      ItemsServices:[]
    }
  }

  static propTypes = {
    getService: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    resume: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    loading: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.resume !== this.props.resume){
      var services  = this.props.resume.services;
      this.setState({
        ItemsServices: services
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getService();  
  }

  slideTo = (i) => this.setState({ currentIndex: i })

  onSlideChanged = (e) => this.setState({ currentIndex: e.item })

galleryItems = () => {
    return this.state.ItemsServices.map((brand, i) => {
      var checkImage = brand.length !== 0 && brand.service_name === "Office";

      console.log(checkImage, "checkImage")
      return (
        <div key={`key-${i}`}  className="card-img-top"><img src={brand.service_image_url} /></div>
      )
    })
  };
 
  render() {
    const { responsive, currentIndex } = this.state
    const items = this.galleryItems();
    return(
        <div>
          <Grid className ="col-12 service-kitchen-gallery-grid" >
            <div className="service-gallery-headline">
                Kitchen
            </div>
              
            <AliceCarousel
              dotsDisabled={true}
              buttonsDisabled={true}
              items={items}
              responsive={responsive}
              slideToIndex={currentIndex}
              onSlideChanged={this.onSlideChanged}
              />
          </Grid>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  resume: state.resume,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getService }) (KitchenService);
```

//Error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ItemsServices' of undefined`

[image]

**service API response**

> (console.log(services))

```
[
  {
    _id: "5f1971da18ba2b04704d65c2",
    service_name: "Other",
    service_image_url:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/tammycloudinary/image/upload/v1595503076/nou0knjbtkujxwjktang.png",
    date: "2020-07-23T11:17:46.928Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f1971b218ba2b04704d65c1",
    service_name: "Bedroom",
    service_image_url:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/tammycloudinary/image/upload/v1595503036/kfiteeilh4doytio6gs8.png",
    date: "2020-07-23T11:17:06.742Z",
    __v: 0,
  }
];
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem, but you will need to return from the function as well - `return this.state.ItemsServices.map...`

Comment: Hi @BrianThompson thank you for your time. could you please elaborate your answer if possible. May be I am missing something here as well.

Comment: Well you are expecting the result of `galleryItems()` to be something to assign to `items`, but the function `galleryItems` does not return anything. You are mapping over the state array (or not since its breaking now) but not returning the result of the map.

Comment: I have updated my code as mentioned but I am getting same kind of error.  Is still I am missing anything here.

Comment: Like I said, that will not fix the current error, but will fix the error that comes *after* this one is fixed. I'm not seeing anything that could cause it yet.. Could you make a runnable example? Can you console log `this` inside the function and add its output to the question?

Comment: I will try to make one runnable example .

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, writing the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not coming from `const items = this.galleryItems();` like I originally thought. It is coming from the constructor.

You are attempting to use the state object in order to build the initial state object. This obviously will not work.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0,
      responsive: { 1024: { items: 3 } },
      galleryItems: this.galleryItems(), // <-- Here is the problem
      services : this.props.resume,
      ...props,
      ItemsServices:[]
    }
  }
```

You attempt to initialize `state` by calling `this.galleryItems`. But that function relies on `this.state` already being declared. Since it has not been created yet (but is in the process of being declared), it is `undefined` and you get this error.

I don't think `gallaryItems` really belongs in state at all. It's generally not recommended to store JSX in state anyway. Instead just use the function like you have in the `render` to compute the JSX needed each render.

Another note: Don't use `this.props` in the constructor. Instead use the `props` that are passed in to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. That is really a nice explanation of my error. I reaaly appreciate your time. I have removed `this.galleryItems` and it is working fine although filtering is not working with `var checkImage = brand.length !== 0 && brand.service_name === "Office";` . I will figure this out for sure. thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Y0u can solve this with this solution as well with `filter`.

```
render() {
    const { services, loading} = this.props.resume;
    var checkImage = services.length === 0 ? [] : services.filter((item) => item.service_name === "Kitchen")
    return(
      <div>

            <OwlCarousel className="owl-theme" loop margin={10} nav>
               {checkImage.map((item, i) => ( 
                <div className="col-xs-12 item" key={item._id} data-id={item._id} >
                  <img className="service-gallery-images" src={item.service_image_url} alt=""/>
                </div>
            ))}
            </OwlCarousel>
      </div>
    )
  }
```